ReadDirectoryChangesW not sending events for files beyond 2GB?
In our application we use ReadDirectoryChangesW() to get notified when a file in a watched folder changes, to e.g. trigger a new examination of the file.
If copying a new file into the watched folder, everything works fine initially - I get notified of all changes that I subscribed for.
But at some point the notifications simply stop. The file is still growing and written as expected, though.
After observing the problem a couple of times I noticed that the stop of notifications seems to correlate with the size of the copy reaching and/or exceeding 2 GB (or rather, presumably 2^31 bytes).
No other operations are done on the watched folder and no errors are returned via the specified completion routine.
This is done using a local NTFS mount on Windows 11.
The folder is not shared.
Looking at the docs I could find no indication that there is an inherent limitation to ReadDirectoryChangesW().
I already tried switching to ReadDirectoryChangesExW(), but to no avail.
So, is there an inherent limitation to this API?
Is there a known way to circumvent it?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Did you try creating a [mre], for example by writing one program to create and write random data to a 3 GB file, and another program to log all notifications for that file? Were you able to reproduce the problem by doing this?

ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR may be you got this status and not restart I/O after this. Anyway you not show your code too

Thanks folks. I will try to set up a minimal reproducible example and update the question as soon as I have it.
Initially I was mostly after whether there is somebody out there that has successfully used the ReadDirectoryChangesW in terms of receiving events beyond 2GB. Would be good to know whether this is "fails as expected" before putting more time into it.

@Bjoern at first filesystem here absolutely not care about size of written data, but only about i/o events count ( but if you copy big file you do this not in single operation but by read/write chunks with constant size, so size in bytes correlated with write count) also fs fill buffer and count operations only after last api call.. in any way you can close file handle after "no notification" and check are will be notify in this case. By fact you say that your i/o not completed in some case and hung in pending state ( you also can use CancelIoEx )

Setting up a minimal reproducible example let me answer my own question:
TLDR
No, there does not seem to be an inherent limitation to ReadDirectoryChangesW() with regard to files growing beyond 2 GB.
The long(er) story
Here is an example that reproduces my problem - kind off.
Running the code, no events are received for the file written by the test most of the time.
Sometimes I get events, sometimes not. Sometimes they stop, sometimes not.
What I can say, is that I definitely got updates beyond 2 GB.
So that part is clarified I guess.
What is interesting is that enabling Line 119 (FlushFileBuffers()) will make me receive an update - for every write I do.
So it looks like I have a caching issue after all.
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

std::atomic<bool> keepRunning(true);

VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped) {
    if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // Cast the buffer to a FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION structure
        FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)lpOverlapped->hEvent;

        std::wstring filename(fni->FileName, fni->FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR));

        // Create a wide string version of the full file path
        std::wstring filePath = L"D:\\TEST\\";
        filePath += filename;

        auto t = std::time(nullptr);
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S") ;
        std::wcout << "\tFile " << filePath << " has been modified.";

        // Open the file
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(filePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ,
                                   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                   NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cout << " Failed to open file for file size with " << GetLastError() << ".\n";
            return;
        }

        // Get the file size
        LARGE_INTEGER fileSize;
        if (!GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fileSize)) {
            std::cout << " Failed to get file size.\n";
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return;
        }

        std::wcout << L" New size: " << fileSize.QuadPart / (1024 * 1024) << L" MiB (" << fileSize.QuadPart << " bytes).\n";

        CloseHandle(hFile);
    } else {
        std::cout << "An error occurred: " << dwErrorCode << "\n";
    }
}

void monitorDirectory() {
    // Open the directory containing the file
    auto watched = L"D:\\TEST\\";
    HANDLE hDir = CreateFileW( watched, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                              FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                              NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                              FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

    if (hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open directory.\n";
        return;
    }

    std::wcout << L"Watching directory " << watched << "\n";

    OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};
    char buffer[64*1024];
    overlapped.hEvent = buffer;
    DWORD bytesReturned;

    // Start watching the directory
    while (keepRunning) {

        // Start watching the directory
        if (!ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir, buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
                                   FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS,
                                   &bytesReturned, &overlapped, FileIOCompletionRoutine)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to setup directory watch.\n";
            CloseHandle(hDir);
            return;
        }

        // Wait for changes
        SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);
    }

    CloseHandle(hDir);
    std::wcout << L"Watch ended on " << watched << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::thread monitorThread(monitorDirectory);

     // Create a file
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(L"D:\\TEST\\file2.txt", GENERIC_WRITE,
                               FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                               NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Write data to the file at 100 MB/s until a key is hit
    const size_t writeSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;  // 100 MB
    char* data = new char[writeSize];
    memset(data, 0, writeSize);  // Fill the data with zeros

    DWORD bytesWritten;
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for( int i = 0; i < 60; i++ ) {
        if (!WriteFile(hFile, data, writeSize, &bytesWritten, NULL)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to write to file.\n";
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            delete[] data;
            return 1;
        }
        //FlushFileBuffers(hFile);
        auto t = std::time(nullptr);
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S") ;
        std::wcout << "\t" << bytesWritten / (1024*1024) << L" MiB written" << std::endl;

        // Sleep to control the write rate
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        if (duration < 1000) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000 - duration));
        }
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    delete[] data;

    // Stop the monitoring thread
    keepRunning = false;
    monitorThread.join();

    return 0;
}

EDIT:
After some more testing, FlushFileBuffers() is the only solid way to ensure consistently getting notifications for growing files while using buffered I/O.
Alternatively unbuffered I/O can be used for writing the files via FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING - if writing of the monitored files can be controlled.
FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH will only partly do the job of FlushFileBuffers() and was not sufficient in my case.
Related reading:

Raymon Chen: Revised notes on the reliability of FlushFileBuffers
Microsoft docs: Caching behavior
Microsoft docs: File Caching

EDIT 2:
Turns out the 2 GB part of the issue was present in our application after all - and a plain bug.
The version of _wstat() used to process the file event simply was not fit to handle file sizes beyond 32-bit.
Using _wstat64() solved the issue.
See also:

Microsoft docs: _wstat


How do C++-developers manage to type delete[]. In 2024. As if std::vector hasn't existed, like, forever.

"Setting up a minimal reproducible example let me answer my own question:" -- Yes, attempting to create a [mre] is a very effective debugging technique in itself.

you not need create dedicated thread here
